# How to enter multiple tasks at once as batch or text import in OmniPlan?

Tags: macos

I want to enter multiple tasks at once. A simple import from a text file might work. I tried copy-paste multiple lines but then they were treated all as one task.

Is there a way to enter multiple tasks in one step?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Which OS is running in question? Version of the app? Bonus would be to show a little research (maybe pointing to the user's guide of the app and explaining what item isn't making sense...) (also - be sure to edit the main post as opposed to commenting here with details).

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste the list into the list of tasks, not into the title of a single task. Make sure you've selected a task, rather than the title field of a task.

- This is the title field selected. ⌘V here pastes the list into the title field of a task.

  [image]
- This is a task selected. ⌘V here pastes the list in as separate tasks.

  [image]